# React-navigation variable tab width

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Where can I set variable tab width rather than fixed in React navigation?

Currently all tabs are same width, need to wrap it to text width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tabBarLabel option in the navigationOptions. Using the style property on a Text element you can then set the width.

```
navigationOptions: {
  tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: 200 }}>Long Tab Title</Text>
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
options={{
           tabBarLabel: () => (
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', width: 200}}>
                  Long Tab Title
              </Text>
            ),
         }}
```