# React Navigation - TabNavigation - one tab to have different width

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

In React Native's `React Navigation` package, I'd like to use `TabNavigation` where **one of the tabs has different width** than the others.

Is there a prop for this in `navigationOptions`? Can't find it in the docs.

Or is there some kind of hack?

Comment: Did you try using `tabStyle` prop?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. The only way (I think) to do this is if you create a custom component for your tab navigator, in which you can do pretty much anything you want.

Comment: See my answer here. I managed to set a specific width via the tabBarLabel option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616248/react-navigation-variable-tab-width/49487727#49487727